# In unity cannot serialise Lists<> using xml serialisation in iPhone alone?

Tags: serialization, reflection, casting, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization

I cannot serialise list types using xml serialisation in iPhone alone but it is working in all platforms. I get the following error when i use the same code in iPhone.

`ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Reflection.MonoProperty:GetterAdapterFrame<System.Collections.Generic.List'1<string>, int> (System.Reflection.MonoProperty/Getter'2<System.Collections.Generic.List'1<string>, int>,object) while running with --aot-only.`

```
at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteListContent (System.Object container, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData listType, System.Xml.Serialization.ListMap map, System.Object ob, System.Text.StringBuilder targetString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteMemberElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem, System.Object memberValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteElementMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObjectElementElements (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob, System.String element, System.String namesp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob, System.String element, System.String namesp, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType, Boolean writeWrappingElem) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteRoot (System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize (System.Object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I tried a lot of serialisation methods nothing is working in iPhone only xml serialisation works. But even in this list serialisation is not working. But it looks like arrays can be serialised.

Comment: you should post the serializing code that provokes this error

Comment: You are likely running in to [this issue](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/250803/executionengineexception-attempting-to-jit-compile.html), and from Mono's [docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/).  Certain collections have dicey aot support w/ respect to generic types.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need XML? If not use json.net serialization.

XML serialization is almost useless in unity ios as most of it is stripped or not you run into JIT vs AOT problems.